# unexpected beginning of statement.(near INSERT INTO departments )

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

All of my sql code is correct and if I try the same thing in other laptop or pc it is working.But why it's not working in my laptop.
What can i do fix the unexpected beginning of statement in mysql Xampp?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQugT.png)

Comment: Please add all statements as text not as image

Comment: The statement looks ok. Have you tried to close phpmyadmin and reopen it?

Comment: Yes but it's not working

Comment: [From stackoverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**. —copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP error message "unexpected beginning of statement" usually indicates a syntax error in the SQL statement being executed. This error can occur due to a variety of reasons, including:

- Missing or incorrect quotes: If the SQL statement contains string literals, they must be enclosed in quotes. If the quotes are missing or incorrect, it can result in a syntax error.
- Incorrect use of reserved words: SQL has a set of reserved words that have a special meaning and cannot be used as identifiers. If a reserved word is used as an identifier, it can result in a syntax error.
- Incorrect use of parentheses: If the SQL statement contains parentheses, they must be used correctly. Incorrect use of parentheses can result in a syntax error.
- Incorrect use of semicolons: SQL statements must be terminated with a semicolon. If the semicolon is missing or incorrectly placed, it can result in a syntax error.
- Incorrect use of commas: If the SQL statement contains a list of values, they must be separated by commas. Incorrect use of commas can result in a syntax error.

To fix the "unexpected beginning of statement" error, you should carefully review the SQL statement and check for any syntax errors. You can also try running the SQL statement in a SQL editor or console to see if it produces any errors.

Current:

```
INSERT INTO departments (id, name) VALUES (001, "Finance");
```

Suggested:

```
-- If your id column can store leading zeros than it is a string column, not numeric
-- and use single quotes for literals
INSERT INTO departments (id, name) VALUES ('001', 'Finance');
```

OR

```
-- If your id is numeric leave out the leading zeros, and use single quotes for literals
INSERT INTO departments (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Finance');
```